# Trying to emulate android from Appcelerator on Windows

Tags: android, sdk, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I installed Appcelerator on Windows, am trying to see android output.

I managed to add an android device by downloading - launching an android emulator called Genymotion. Now I have an IP address added to the Run menu, when I activate it Appcelerator tries to launch: console messages appear. But after 1minute or so I get a message saying I should download an SDK API level 23.

I had an old version of Android Studio, I updated it, opened its SDK manager tool and downloaded everything I could find, rebooted, but error persists. I can see Android version 23 in the list.

Here is the error message:

[ERROR] : No valid Android SDK targets found.

[ERROR] : Please download an Android SDK target API level 23 or newer from the Android SDK Manager and try again

Comment: You can use the appcelerator CLI to check you configuration.
Try to inspect to output of this command in `appc ti info`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently and it turned out to be the java JDK missing from my path.

Take a close look at the [Appcelerator environment variable documentation for windows](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Software_Locations_and_Environment_Variables-section-29004844_SoftwareLocationsandEnvironmentVariables-Windows).

Below are some java directories included in my path on my new Windows 10 machine:

- C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\java;
- C:\android-sdk-win\tools;
- C:\android-sdk-win\platform-tools;
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;

Also, I really suggest using **GenyMotion** (which I avoided for years) to run your emulators, turns out to be incredibly fast, easy to setup and they have [free Basic Version](https://www.genymotion.com/pricing-and-licensing/).

Best of luck.

Comment: The recent Android AVDs are equally as fast as Genymotion and come with Google Play Services.

Comment: Hi Newport99, thanks for your answer. Here is the path items I have relating to java and sdk: C:\android-sdk-win;C:\android-sdk-win\tools;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
Would changing emulators have any chance of solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I have an IP address added to the Run menu

Studio should detect Android & Genymotion emulators and allow you to select from a list. No need to enter the IP. If you don't see the emulators, run `appc ti info -t android` to see if there's any issues that need fixing.

Comment: Hi Fokke, thanks for your input. I didn't type in the IP, the IP appeared by itself. I could not find the appc command on the disk.

Comment: Studio will install the CLI for you. If you open PowerShell you should be able to run the above command.